# Prove that x is transitive iff $\bigcup x \subseteq x $

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I don't know how to prove this. The definition of the a transitive set is $$ X \text{ is transitive} \Leftrightarrow \forall y \text{ }\forall z ( (z \in y \vee z \in x) \rightarrow z\in x)) $$

Comment: The question in the body is just the definition of transitive

Comment: Have you tried to verify the definition of transitive from $\bigcup x\subseteq x$; and vice versa?

Comment: @AsafKaragila My idea was to take a $y \in \bigcup x$ and prove that $y$ is also in $x$. But i think my arguments are very poor. (Sorry about my english)

Comment: @AndresMejia Sorry, i just correct the question and put the definition that i have in my notes.

Comment: That is *not* how you prove a set is transitive. Write down the following sentence (complete the blanks). "Suppose that $\bigcup x\subseteq x$. We want to show that $x$ is transitive, meaning (blank). Let $y\in x$ and let $z\in y$, then by the assumption (blank), and therefore $z\in x$."

Comment: Why did you delete your cool other question about $\phi(t) = e^{At}$?  I had a cool answer I was just about to enter!  Consider undeleting it?

Comment: Actually it's OK; I already answered it here:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1489371/if-phi0-i-identity-and-that-phits-phit-phis-for-all-t-s-in-ma?rq=1

Comment: Sorry @RobertLewis but a few seconds after publish it I find out that some else already ask it and I dont want to repeat questions... However the answer that i found its yours, that's a coincidence. Thanks anyway!

Comment: It's OK, I've had my shot at it.  I'd forgotten about that old one!  Cheers!

Comment: @RobertLewis I undelete the answer 'cause i have some questions about your proof